# How to migrate azure data factory to another data center

Tags: azure, migration, azure-data-factory

We have a Azure Data Factory, hosted in *EastUS* data center. We want to move that to *WestUS* data center, as our VMs reside in the *WestUS* datacenter. Moving VMs to *EastUS* data center is tougher option, as VMs hold databases of size > 4 Tera Bytes. Creating another data factory in *WestUS* data center will be difficult, as we will lose all our previous pipeline execution logs.

There are options available for move to different resource group, different subscription. But, not sure on how to move a data factory to new data center location.

Please help.

Comment: You may refer the documentation for Migrating Azure services to new regions: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/migrating-azure-services-to-new-regions/ and see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice how Azure Data Factory (under the Analytics category) is [not available in West US](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/services/?) but that Data Movement is. So don't stress about which region Azure Data Factory lives in. The small API calls it makes to execute a stored proc in your database will cross region and incur a tiny amount of egress charge but so little it is not worth worrying about. If Azure Data Factory does any Copy Activities they will occur using Data Movement resources in West US if data is being copied from West US to West US.

If the egress charges on your Azure bill prove otherwise then please clarify what ADF is doing exactly.